# Laravel v5.5 - Redirection after login loses secure (https) connection

Tags: laravel, redirect, https, authentication

My site, hosted on Heroku, forces all routes to be https via the .htaccess file, regardless of middleware of auth or guest.

The site experiences an issue when using a URL that requires auth middleware (forcing a login) that upon successful login and redirection back to the original URL, the browser shows a "Not secure" tag and it's no longer https.

In the browser, refreshing doesn't make it secure.  A different link needs to be clicked before it returns to being secure.

Is this a known issue or is there a way to get around this issue?

I've attached the constructor of the LoginController which is handling redirection:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (url()->previous()) {
            $this->redirectTo = url()->previous();
        } else {
            $this->redirectTo = env('APP_URL').'/dashboard';
        }
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
```

I'm willing to attach any other relevant code snippets but I'm not sure what they'd be or I'd have already included them.

Comment: What is `url` in `config/app.php`?

Comment: it's also likely that the APP url is set in the .env file. In this case the value in app.php would be overridden and you should show us APP_URL from your .env file too.

Comment: The value in config/app.php is:  'url' => env('APP_URL') and the variable is set in Heroku's environment.  The .env file's value, only valid on my localhost dev machine, is APP_URL=http://localhost.  The .env file is it the .gitignore file and so it should not be present in either of my test or production https environments.  I just verified that the APP_URL setting is the https://url I expect it to be.